# Javascript function call on wrong pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, jquery-mobile

Heyo,

Having a few issues with JavaScript function calls. Basically I am using php to create a table, and then on page init JavaScript is called to click a button which is labelled correct answer.

Now this all works fine, however when I return to the main page and try to do the same thing again it fails due to an *"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'click' of null"*. This is happening because for some reason the script is being incorrectly called again and is then trying to click on something which isn't there, hence the 'null' error.

If I reload the page it works fine again as the JavaScript function is then not loaded until called.

The main issue seems to be that the JavaScript is remaining loaded (probably because jquerymobile uses ajax calls to load the page, and thus the data is never properly refreshed. Other than forcing the page to load without ajax, any suggestions?

**JavaScript function:**

```
function showCorrectAnswer(correctAnswer) {
    $(document).on("pageinit", function() {
        document.getElementById(correctAnswer).click()
    })
}
```

**PHP function:**

```
function populatedQuestionUI ($topicID, $questionID, $actionSought) {
global $pdo;

$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE Topic = ? and QNo = ?");
$query->bindValue(1, $topicID);
$query->bindValue(2, $questionID);
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}

?>
<form name="questionUI" action="/MCExamSystemV2/Admin/manageQuestion.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="TopicID" value="<?php echo $_POST['topic']; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="QuestionNo" value="<?php echo $_POST['question']; ?>"/>
    <label for="QText">Question Text</label>
    <input type="text" name="QText" value="<?php echo $results[0]['QText']; ?>"/>
    <label for="AnswerText-1">First Answer</label>
    <input type="Text" name="AnswerText-1" value="<?php echo $results[0]['AText1']; ?>"/>
    <label for="AnswerText-2">Second Answer</label>
    <input type="Text" name="AnswerText-2" value="<?php echo $results[0]['AText2']; ?>"/>
    <label for="AnswerText-3">Third Answer</label>
    <input type="Text" name="AnswerText-3" value="<?php echo $results[0]['AText3']; ?>"/>
    <label for="AnswerText-4">Fourth Answer</label>
    <input type="Text" name="AnswerText-4" value="<?php echo $results[0]['AText4']; ?>"/>
    <label for="CorrectAnswer">Correct answer:</label>
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="button" name="Answer-1" id="Answer-1" value=1 onClick="document.getElementById('CorrectAnswer').value='1'"/>
        <input type="button" name="Answer-2" id="Answer-2" value=2 onClick="document.getElementById('CorrectAnswer').value='2'"/>
        <input type="button" name="Answer-3" id="Answer-3" value=3 onClick="document.getElementById('CorrectAnswer').value='3'"/>
        <input type="button" name="Answer-4" id="Answer-4" value=4 onClick="document.getElementById('CorrectAnswer').value='4'"/>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="CorrectAnswer" id="CorrectAnswer" value='0'/>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm <?php echo $actionSought; ?>">
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onClick="location.href='/MCExamSystemV2/Admin'"/>
</form>

<script src="/MCExamSystemV2/includes/scripts.js"></script>>
<script>showCorrectAnswer('Answer-<?php echo $results[0]['CorrectA']; ?>')</script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: `pageinit` fires once, replace it with `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: I only want it to fire once; when the php function creates the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is because you're doing this:

```
document.getElementById(correctAnswer).click();
```

You're not checking if the element is on the page. Change it to:

```
var el = document.getElementById(correctAnswer);
if (el) {
    el.click();
}
```

Comment: Do you know why it would be called outside of that specific php function? This does seem to fix the issue but it seems more of a work-around than an actual solution to the problem (which is the JS function being called incorrectly).

Comment: Js is not "executed" inside a function. PHP's job is only to process strings - in this case a bunch of HTML and javascript. That big lump of string is then sent to the browser where it is parsed and executed (hopefully, if it's generated correctly by PHP). Without knowing how the rest of your app is structured I can't know why that piece of script is exectued. It's usually better to look at the full generated HTML instead of the PHP code when trying to debug stuff like this.

Comment: So the script at the bottom of the function is not actually called by the PHP function it just happens as the reader parses through on the include_once? As to the code itself its on github.com/rayrn/MCExamSystemV2.

Comment: Correct. From PHP's point of view the script is just a string.

Comment: Okay so following that logic, shouldn't the client only get sent that string when the populatedQuestionID(...) function is called?

Assuming that is the case, is the only way to force the site to 'forget' that the string is there, to refresh the page or is there a drop JavaScript file function that I am unaware of.

Mostly I think the issue is ajax page loading being screwy so if that is the case then I guess that the if statement is the only way round it...

Comment: Yes, in theory. Which is why I said that I can't know how that script got sent to the browser without knowing the rest of your code. You should look at the generated HTML (view source) to figure out what's happening.